# GTW Session compatibility issues Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to work through the below dependency issues and would be interested in some guidance.

Th last two with Firebase auth and mobile scanner seem like they shouldn't have an issue. The first Seems like it should be ok with version over 1.2, so I can't really see the problem.

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":   In Podfile:
> ar_flutter_plugin (from `.symlinks/plugins/ar_flutter_plugin/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.2, which depends on
> ARCore/CloudAnchors (~> 1.32.0) was resolved to 1.32.0, which depends on
> GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.2)
>
> ```
> firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.6.1, which depends on
>   Firebase/Auth (= 10.9.0) was resolved to 10.9.0, which depends on
>     FirebaseAuth (~> 10.9.0) was resolved to 10.9.0, which depends on
>       GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 4.0, >= 2.1)
>
> mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
>   GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
>     MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
>       MLKitVision (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
>         GTMSessionFetcher/Core (< 3.0, >= 1.1)
> ```